# ValueError while parsing a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, tuples

My script is-

```
import subprocess
z = subprocess.check_output(['python3', 'test1.py'],universal_newlines=True)
mas = z
mas = dict(mas)
e = mas.get('email')
print(e)
```

I get an error-

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

But when I run-

```
mas = {'email': 'something@gmail.com'}
mas = dict(mas)
e = mas.get('email')
print(e)
```

I get the desired output i.e `something@gmail.com`.
Also, the output of `test1.py` is `{'email': 'something@gmail.com'}`

Comment: `check_output` returns a string.

Comment: @bereal So how can I get the exact output?

Comment: Is there any reason why you *run* ``test1.py``, instead of just importing it?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi No, not really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`check_output()` returns the process output as a string. If you know that it represents a Python dictionary, you can parse it using [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast
import subprocess

z = subprocess.check_output(['python3', 'test1.py'], universal_newlines=True)
mas = ast.literal_eval(z)
```

That said, I'd rather import the python file as a module and use the functions in it directly.